# Multiple instances of the same website/adding a prefix to the URL [ASP.NET MVC]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building a ASP.NET MVC app. Currently the website is one 'platform' but the goal is to enable users logged in as the SuperAdmin role to open different instances of the website (e.g. for another city).

Say if our current url is www.mywebsite.com, how can I achieve multiple instances of this website like www.cityX.mywebsite.com or www.cityY.mywebsite.com? The cityX or cityY part would be the name of the platform as entered in by the SuperAdmin.

I'm relatively new to this, so sorry if this is a vague question. Any hints or reading material leading me into the right way would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you truly want separate instances of the website then this has more to do with server configuration than MVC, so is therefore more appropriate to ask over at http://serverfault.com/. The setup you're looking to do involves hosting multiple subdomains (for http://xyz.somedomain.com - the xyz is called a subdomain). You could then use some kind of Single Sign On solution to manage the user logon across the different instances.

Comment: @StephenLloyd Thanks for the answer man. I had no idea this approach would involve all of this. It's just a school project so I am sticking to websitename.com/city, which seems to be far easier to implement. Thanks for the insight though, I will now close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would just open a new site on the web server for each specific city DNS. When the superadmin change city, redirect them to the given city site.

Comment: this should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Wasn't allowed to comment...new user here..feels great to be met by your enthusiasm.......